Wagtail: HEIC image upload
I'm trying to upload HEIC image file in the wagtail admin panel using image chooser widget.
I have updated my settings based on this
WAGTAILIMAGES_EXTENSIONS = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "heic", "heif"]

Now, when trying to upload, I see the correct message Supported formats: PNG, JPG, JPEG, GIF, HEIC, HEIF. Maximum filesize: 25.0 MB. , but when I click on file chooser - there is no option to select any heic file.
Tried this on wagtail 6.0.6 and 5.2.6

Current releases of Wagtail do not support HEIC images. The WAGTAILIMAGES_EXTENSIONS setting is only really meant to specify a subset of allowed image types out of the ones that Wagtail has implemented support for (which includes the familiar ones such as PNG and JPEG, plus SVG, WebP and AVIF) - just adding a new type to the list won't make immediately make it supported.
However, since most of the prerequisites for HEIC support are already in place, I've now submitted a pull request for consideration in the upcoming Wagtail 6.3 release: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/12384

Many thanks for that
